# Completely remove Outlook up and start afresh

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I want to delete all my Outlook accounts, remove all configurations and everything and start afresh. Basically, like do a complete reset. But, it doesn't let me remove my last account saying something about data files and all. How do I nuke Outlook and start afresh? I'm using Outlook 2013

Comment: Can't you create a new account and then delete that last one which you weren't allowed to get rid of earlier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ensure you get a complete reset, uninstall it, delete the data files and reinstall.

Here are instructions to help if you need them; [Install or remove individual Office programs and components](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/install-or-remove-individual-office-programs-and-components-HA010354261.aspx)

Comment: Where are the data files? Which all locations? Want to confirm

Comment: By default the data files are located at `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook`. Check out [Locating the Outlook data files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/locating-the-outlook-data-files-HA103412630.aspx).

Comment: The link @CharlieRB provided no longer works.

Answer (score 54):

Re-installing is waste of time...

just go to control panel>>mail(32bit)>>show profiles>delete all profiles here.

then open the outlook, you will be opening an fresh account.

NOTE:1.before deleting don't forget to take mail backup.

NOTE:2. On windows 8, 8.1 and 10 you can use <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and select Control Panel.

Comment: Wish I knew this earlier!

Comment: Here on Windows 8.1 Mail does not show up, not even in the search. I have to switch to *Category View* and then go to *User Accounts and Family Safety* and there I have a Mail icon. ?-)

Comment: *Control Panel* > ***User Accounts*** > *Mail(32-bit)* > *Show Profiles* > *Remove*

Comment: This worked after hours of debugging issues with Outlook, including a Repair. Can't believe this config isn't accessible within Outlook itself.

Comment: OP asked to reinstall, not delete profiles...

Answer (score 8):

Shockingly, you can delete all your profiles and even uninstall, reboot, and reinstall Outlook and still have nasty issues that linger.

Some stuff that will not be reset includes....

- Any VBA scrips
- Any ribbon bar customizations
- The database of which emails have already been downloaded via POP3

...and lots of other stuff that can haunt you.

To *completely* reset Outlook, you must....

1. Uninstall the Outlook application
2. Delete all the profiles
3. Delete the tree under the registry key 
   `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office]`
   (or you can go in and only delete the sub-trees for your Outlook version if you want to keep state for other Office applications)
4. Delete (or rename to a .bak) the folder `C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office` or `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Office`
5. Delete (or rename to a .bak) the folder `C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office` or `%appdata%\Microsoft\Office`
6. Delete (or just don't use) the previous PST file.

I only know all this because I had a nasty problem where Outlook started downloading messages over POP3 and then deleting them. Deleting all profiles, PST files, and uninstalling/reinstalling did not solve the problem. Only after following all the above steps did the problem go away. I still can't figure out exactly where the POP3 messages database is actually stored.

Comment: I tried this and hit a snag. Even a system restore wouldn't recover it properly. It got stuck on 'Profile loading' following re-install. At that point, I had to open in it safe mode (run > outlook.exe /safe) and set up a new profile as detailed here - http://www.intowindows.com/outlook-2016-hangs-at-processing-starting-or-loading-profile-screen/

Answer (score 6):

In the recent versions of Outlook the Mail option in the Control Panel has been removed. Even so, you can use the `/profiles` switch for `outlook.exe` to open the Outlook Mail Profiles window even if Outlook accounts are hosed.

Run `outlook.exe /profiles` from the start menu to open the Profile selection window. Now click `options` then `delete`. If warned about data loss you'll need to confirm removal. Repeat for any other profiles.

If you want to remove the PST, OST & NK2 files (effectively *all* your data so caveat emptor) you can delete them from the folders:

1. `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook`
2. `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Outlook Files`

Now re-open Outlook and you'll be prompted to create a new profile and add an email address to it.

The entire process can be completed in under 5 minutes, but you'll then need to re-download all your email so expect that to take some time for people with large mail archives.