# Connecting Outlook / Windows to Office365 Account fails with Error 83750009: "JSON value not found

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, windows-11, microsoft-outlook-2019

[enter image description here][1]Since changing the primary mail address of my Office 365 account, I am no longer able to set it up in Outlook.

At first, all I could do was not retrieve any mail, so I tried to set up the account again - unfortunately unsuccessfully.

Every time I try to add the account, I get the error `83750009: "JSON value not found."`.

After that I removed the profile, uninstalled the whole Office and removed remaining references / registry keys as described here:

https://superuser.com/a/1045016/874560

I have also tried setting up the account, as an Azure-AD account, directly in Windows. Here I get the same error message.

Unfortunately the problem still persists, even Microsoft support could not solve the problem after 10 days. Do any of you have any ideas?

[image: Error Message Outlook]

Comment: Can you log in to owa successfully? And how did you add the account? It is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and then add the account to check if there are some differences. In addition, about the error, if possible, please provide screenshots of relevant problems. (In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy, please remember to hide your personal information)

Comment: @Christy Yes, I can log in with the account via the web interface without any problems. I can set up another user from the same tenant in Outlook without any issues. The error only occurs with this user. I have added the screenshots in the main post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used a translator to translate this error report and done research on it. Combined with your description, this problem seems to be related to the account. It is recommended that you continue to contact Microsoft support for timely progress.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to show results of
get-mailbox |FL
get-azureaduser |FL
get-msoluser |FL
Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice

Does it happen only on a single device?

Try removing the device from AzureAD and
dsregcmd.exe /debug /leave
to remove the machine and try re-registering it.